# Не работает функция для события onclick на ссылке

Tags: javascript, python, html, onclicklistener

У меня не работает `onclick` на ссылке. Онклик должен перенаправлять в .js файл, а функция в .js файле должна делать post запрос на адрес /make-seen, запросы на этот адрес обрабатывает функция написанная питоне с flask. И создается ощущение что запрос на части js не делается, потому что в консоли нет сообщений о перенаправлении на адрес /make-seen. Я читал, что советовали в `onclick` писать еще и `return false;` но все безуспешно. Добавлю еще что js не знаю, и написал функцию на подобии той, что писалась в одном туториале. Собственно вопрос: что надо такое сделать чтобы делались запросы на адрес /make-seen?

HTML:

```html
<a onclick="makeSeen(2, 33173, 1. Анализ информационных моделей);return false;" href="https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=33173" target="_blank">33173</a>
```

JS:

```js
function makeSeen(userId, problemId, topicName){
    fetch('/make-seen', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            userId: userId,
            problemId: problemId,
            topicName: topicName
        })
    }).then((_res) => {
        window.location.href = '/';
    });
}
```

Python:

```py
@views.route('/make-seen', methods=['POST'])
def make_seen():
    data = loads(request.data)
    user_id = int(data['userId'])
    problem_id = data['problemId']
    topic_name = data['topicName']

    if user_id == current_user.id:
        seen_tasks = json.loads(current_user.seen_tasks)
        seen_tasks[topic_name].append(problem_id)
        current_user.seen_tasks = json.dumps(seen_tasks)
            
        db.session.commit()
    
    return jsonify({})
```

Comment: Покажите какой HTML элемент получился в итоге.

Comment: @OliverPatterson поправил

Comment: <a onclick="makeSeen('2', '33173', '1. Анализ информационных моделей')" href="https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=33173" target="_blank">33173</a>

Comment: В хтмл строке в посте видно, что третье значение без кавычек указано, конечно дело врятли в этом будет. Но возможно это вызывает ошибку при вызове функции, аля переменная нот деклоратед.

Comment: @Lukas  спасибо помогло

Comment: @OliverPatterson спасибо все работает